# Flask, WTForms open multiple urls in new tab

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am building a small app with Flask to reboot multiple IP-based devices. I want to have a checklist of the devices that when I can go through and on submit it will open that ip/rebootpage.html. As of right now my code tries to combine all of the data from the form/rebootpage. Here is what I have so far:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import widgets,SelectMultipleField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "565&SDdsa7fgSdst7%6"

Test_Choices = [('10.202.214.196', '#61'), ('10.202.214.197', '#62')]
Test_Choices_NR = [('10.202.214.198', 'Net Relay 1')]


class RebootForm(FlaskForm):
    available = SelectMultipleField('Available', choices=Test_Choices,
                                    option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                    widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    availableNR = SelectMultipleField('Available Net Relays', choices=Test_Choices_NR,
                                      option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                      widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))


@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = RebootForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        list = '{}'.format(form.available.data).replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
        for each in list:
            return redirect('http://{}/rc.cgi?L=uirreboot.html&c=99'.format(each))
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Actually it's hard to understand what you try to achieve and how. Could you rewrite your question?

Answer (score 0):

A little asking around the IRC got me to my answer. The answer is I have to use requests (not request, there are 2 different things). My final code looks like this and works great. Note that requests makes the requests without ever opening the page.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
import requests
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import widgets,SelectMultipleField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "565&SDdsa7fgSdst7%6"

All_Selected = [('Everything', 'Entire Site')]
Test_Choices = [('10.202.214.196', '#61'), ('10.202.214.197', '#62')]
Test_Choices_NR = [('10.202.214.198', 'Net Relay 1')]


class RebootForm(FlaskForm):
    all_selected = SelectMultipleField('Select All', choices=All_Selected,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    available = SelectMultipleField('Available', choices=Test_Choices,
                                    option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                    widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    availableNR = SelectMultipleField('Available Net Relays', choices=Test_Choices_NR,
                                      option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                      widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))


@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = RebootForm()
    ugly_messages = []
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ip_addresses = form.available.data
        for ip_address in ip_addresses:
            try:
                requests.get('http://{}/rc.cgi?L=uirreboot.html&c=99'.format(ip_address))
                ugly_messages.append('rebooting {}'.format(ip_address))
                ugly_messages.append('Please wait 30 secs.')
            except Exception:
                ugly_messages.append('{} did not reboot. It may be offline.'.format(ip_address))
        ip_addressesNR = form.availableNR.data
        for ip_addressNR in ip_addressesNR:
            try:
                requests.get('http://{}/setup.cgi?L=uireboot2.html&R'.format(ip_addressNR))
                ugly_messages.append('rebooting {}'.format(ip_addressNR))
                ugly_messages.append('Please wait 30 secs.')
            except Exception:
                ugly_messages.append('{} did not reboot. It may be offline.'.format(ip_addressNR))
        return "<br/>".join(ugly_messages)
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```